# How to send success or failure status to AJAX calls from Asp.Net Web API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an asp.net C# Web API project. I am posting data from a client using jQuery AJAX. The code is given below. I have tried two types of AJAX calls as shown below. Whether the API succeeds or not, the code under either success or error is never reached in the AJAX.

```
Asp.Net Web API Code: 

[HttpPost]
    [Route("SendCustomerDetails")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendCustomerDetails([FromBody] String jsonData)
    {

     //Code to process json
     //...
     //...
     resp = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("customer/newcustomer", jObject);

        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
              //log resp
              return Created(Request.RequestUri.ToString(), resp.StatusCode);
        }
        else{
          //log resp
          return Created(Request.RequestUri.ToString(), resp.StatusCode);
        }
}

Jquery AJAX code1:
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:49918/SendCustomerDetails',
            dataType: 'json',
            //data: jsonData,
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert("Success: " + data);
            $('#value1').text(data);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("failure: " + jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
            $('#value1').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
        });

Jquery AJAX code2:
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:49918/SendCustomerDetails',
            dataType: 'json',
            //data: jsonData,
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: " + data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
            
        });
```

Comment: Can you post   jsonData too. I need to see what are you trying to post/

Answer (score 0):

fix the action

```
     [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/SendCustomerDetails")]
    public IActionResult SendCustomerDetails(JObject model)
    {
       return Ok(" It is Success");
    }
```

try  this code

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:49918/SendCustomerDetails',
            data: { model:jsonData},
           success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
            
        });
```

Comment: I tried it. Still, the alert on either success or error is reached!

Comment: @Kim Do you have any problem now? Does it go to the controller action?

Comment: Yes, the AJAX call goes to the controller. But whether it succeeds or not, nothing is returned to AJAX.

Comment: @Kim I changed ajax, pls try again. And could you post jsonData too? I would like to check it. It could be a problem.